# Trying to populate worker ID using Compay Name but only the first worker in that company is displayed in dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

This is the view page code in code Igniter.
I am able to populated the second drop down(worker Id) but the problem is, only first data is being fetched. As it has more than 50 worker, only 1 worker id is being fetched.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name_of').change(function() {
        var Worker_id = $('#name_of').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:{data:Worker_id},
            dataType:'text',
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>supply_chain/get_filtered_names_for_time_card",
            success:function(result) {
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                $('#Worker').empty();
                for(i in result) {
                    $('#Worker').append("<option value='"+result[i]['Worker_id']+"'>"+result[i]['Worker_id']+" "+result[i]['Worker_name']+"</option>")
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the Controller function for above View through which I am trying to get all workers related to that required company name.

```
public function get_filtered_names_for_time_card() {
    $id = $this->input->post('data');
    $companyName = $this->supply_model->get_all_names_for_time_card();
    for($i = 0;$i < sizeof($companyName);$i++){
        if($companyName[$i]['company_name'] == $id){
            $data['companyNameOptions'] = [$companyName[$i]];
            break;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($data['companyNameOptions']);
}
```

Comment: You know what `break` does, right?

Comment: Yes, I know but when removing "break"  it is selecting the last one leaving all data above it. @u_mulder

Comment: The jquery in your view page needs to go into a JS file. This is not a solution, just a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

It would be a much better idea to make the query select only the row you want but your problem with the code you have written is you over writing the data each time round your loop

Also once you find a `company_name` you want you terminate the for loop with a `break` so you will only ever add one to the resulting `$data` array

```
public function get_filtered_names_for_time_card()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('data');
    $companyName = $this->supply_model->get_all_names_for_time_card();
    for($i = 0;$i < sizeof($companyName);$i++){
        if($companyName[$i]['company_name'] == $id){
            $data['companyNameOptions'][] = $companyName[$i];
            // note here               ^^
            //break;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($data['companyNameOptions']);
}
```

Also the `$data` array does not need to have a sub array so above code can be written more simply and clearly as

```
public function get_filtered_names_for_time_card()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('data');
    $companyName = $this->supply_model->get_all_names_for_time_card();
    for($i = 0;$i < sizeof($companyName);$i++){
        if($companyName[$i]['company_name'] == $id){
            $data[] = $companyName[$i];
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And in your javascript, if you are returning JSON then tell the ajax call that you are doing that and you can forget about the  `JSON.parse()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#name_of').change(function(){
          var Worker_id = $('#name_of').val();

          $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              data:{data:Worker_id},

              //dataType:'text',
              dataType:'json',

              url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>supply_chain/get_filtered_names_for_time_card",
              success:function(result)
              {
                  //result = JSON.parse(result);
                    $('#Worker').empty();
                    for(i in result){
                        $('#Worker').append("<option value='"+result[i]['Worker_id']+"'>"+result[i]['Worker_id']+" "+result[i]['Worker_name']+"</option>")
                    }
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: After commenting out the dataType: 'text' and json.parse(result), the whole data transformed into Undefined data.

Comment: You did add the `dataType:'json',` I assume?

Comment: all data simply transformed into Undefined @RiggsFolly

Comment: Well leave that suggestion out. Get the PHP working correctly and then try and add the js changes

Comment: Wooho.. Thank you.  Its working perfectly fine now :)

Comment: Sudeep, select RiggsFolly as the answer you choose by hitting the checkmark next to his answer